# C : Access violation reading location with malloc

Tags: c, struct, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings

I want to allocate memory to structures in function and assign the values given as parameters to the function.
My code:

**linkedList.c**

```
FrameNode* createFrameNode(char name[MAX_NAME], int duration, char path[MAX_PATH])
{
    Frame* newFrame = malloc(sizeof(Frame));
    FrameNode* newNode = malloc(sizeof(FrameNode));

    // Copy name
    strcpy(newFrame->name, name);

    // Add duration and path
    newFrame->duration = duration;
    strcpy(newFrame->path, path);

    // Attach new frame to the new node
    newNode->frame = newFrame;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    return newNode;
}
```

I get an error back:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFF18C4D215 (ucrtbased.dll) in C_Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
```

If I try to get any memory related to the structs.
Can you tell what is wrong from my code?

The structs in **linkedList.h**

```
// Frame struct
typedef struct Frame
{
    char* name;
    unsigned int duration;
    char* path;
} Frame;


// Link (node) struct
typedef struct FrameNode
{
    Frame* frame;
    struct FrameNode* next;
} FrameNode;
```

Comment: You haven't allocated memory to the `struct` members. So `strcpy(newFrame->name, name);` will fail. But `newFrame->name = name;` will be OK (although if the source changes so will this data). Alternatively `newFrame->name = strdup(name);`

Comment: What do you mean by function members?

Comment: Typo sorry - corrected.

Comment: @איתמרשיאון After `Frame* newFrame = malloc(sizeof(Frame));`, `newFrame->name` is uninitialized and just points to some random memory location.  You need to initialize it correctly before using it.  Likewise for `newFrame->path` .

Comment: God bless you!!

Comment: Is there a compelling reason for your `struct`  to use pointer variables as opposed to simple `char` arrays?  (if you are not constrained, it would simplify the code to make that change.)  `char* name;` -> `char name[80];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data member `name` of the structure `struct Frame` has the pointer type `char *`

```
// Frame struct
typedef struct Frame
{
    char* name;
    unsigned int duration;
    char* path;
} Frame;
```

After this allocation of memory for an object of the type `struct Frame`

```
Frame* newFrame = malloc(sizeof(Frame));
```

the data member `name` has an indeterminate value.

So this call of `strcpy`

```
// Copy name
strcpy(newFrame->name, name);
```

invokes undefined behavior.

You need to allocate memory where you are going to copy the string pointed to by the pointer `name` like for example

```
// Copy name
newFrame->name = malloc( strlen( name ) + 1 );
strcpy(newFrame->name, name);
```

The same problem exists for the data member `path`. That is you need to allocate a character array where you are going to copy the string pointed to by the pointer `path`.

In general you should check that all memory allocations were successful.

Pay attention to that these parameter declarations `char name[MAX_NAME]` and `char path[MAX_PATH]` are adjusted by the compiler to the declarations `char *name` and `char *path`. These parameters should be declared with qualifier `const` because the passed strings are not changed within the function.

```
FrameNode* createFrameNode(const char name[MAX_NAME], int duration, const char path[MAX_PATH]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also not uncommon to simplify life by not including pointer members into a `struct` in the first place.  Although they do have their place, if not absolutely necessary, the memory allocation and freeing steps required will add unnecessary complication to the code...

So, unless you are constrained to use pointers, just use `char` arrays instead.

```
// Frame struct
typedef struct Frame
{
    char name[80];
    unsigned int duration;
    char path[MAX_PATH_LEN];//or whatever define is provided on your system
} Frame;
```